# how to mock a module in supertest by using jest??

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

guys!

I am using Jest and Supertest to test my node server code.

Here is my `server.js`

```
// server.js
const config = require('./lib/config')
...
const app = new koa()
...
module.exports = app
```

I want to mock `config.js` while I used Supertest, here is my `server.test.js`

```
// server.test.js
const supertest = require('supertest-as-promised')
describe('xxxxxx', ()=>{
  let app,server
  beforeEach(()=>{
    jest.mock('lib/config',()=>({
      uri: '/path',
      apiPrefix: '/prefix'
    }))
    app = require('server')
  })

  afterEach(()=>{
    server && server.close()
    app=null
    server=null
  })

  it('should success', async ()=>{
    server || (server = app.listen(0))
    const request = supertest(server)
    request().get('path/prefix_home').expect(200)
  })
})
```

I have printed `config` in `server.js` while running test,but the print information showed that `jest.mock` did not work(path of `lib/config` is correct).

Anyone has any idea of mocking `config.js` in such situation by using Supertest??

Comment: In `server.js`, you require `./lib/config` and in your test `lib/config` and that is not the strict equal string. Problem could be here

Answer (score 0):

Jest appear to resolve paths, so the path you provide while mocking has to be consistent: it should be `./lib/config` if `server.test.js` is located next to `server.js`. If the files are in different places, you'll need to construct the path accordingly, e.g. 
`../src/lib/config` 
if your server.js is in src folder and server.test.js is located in test folder next to src